# Why we do we get the stored item in character type array (char arr[] = "abc";when we print it like " cout << arr<< endl;

Tags: c++, arrays

Why we dont get the address of character type array (char arr[] = "abc";when we print it like " cout << arr<<  endl;  but if we print a integer array we get the address of the a[0]?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[] ={1,2,3};
    char b[] = "abc";
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b <<  endl;
}
```

in output i got the memmory address of a but for b i got abc please explain why

Comment: The C++ standard library provides `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream, char const*);`  A char array decays into a pointer.  That is not provided for `int const*`, so `void const*` is the best match for an `int` array (after pointer decay), which prints out the pointer value.

Comment: From the olden days of C, `char` arrays are used to hold strings, so most of the standard library code treats `char*` as a pointer to the first element of a nul-terminated sequence of characters.